# (Google Analytics) - Tracking 'add to cart / Add to favorite' data in NopCommerce web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, nopcommerce

I have enabled Google Analytics plugin for my NopCommerce application and added my Google Analytics Id.
Also, It's working fine with site traffic and visited pages(see attached images).

This is the script on the layout page.
[image]

**But I need to enable enhanced e-commerce analytics, such as Add/Remove Cart, Add to Wishlist, Add to Compare, Checkout, etc.**

Currently, NopCommerce Invoke google analytics submits function when the page is loading when the root page refreshing.

But I don't have any idea to implement it for NopCommerce buttons events. eg: Add to Cart.

With the way NopCommerce code developed, I have no idea to push these actions when after the button click.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-data

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show the output of script, pls

Comment: script image uploaded to the question. function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];gtag("js",new Date);gtag("config","UA-1xxxxxx");gtag("set",{user_id:"9899412"})

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a plugin for Enhanced Ecommerce too (the ecommerce mentioned in the screenshot is standard ecommerce not enhanced. That means only transaction, not add to cart or other detailed information).

Doing it manually requires non-trivial development and system knowledge of both the Analytics constructs and the CMS in question.

If you do a search on the net you will find the plugin among the first results.